# Should I need a key to store such type of JSON data in MySQL?

Tags: mysql

I am totally new to JSON data type in MySQL. I installed MySQL 5.7.34 a few days ago and now I'm playing around with it.

So, I have following table in `MySQL 5.7.34`:

```
CREATE TABLE tb_products (
    product_id int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, 
    product_name varchar(255) NOT NULL, 
    product_attributes json NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (product_id)
);
```

One of the row in this table looks like as:

[image]

**product_attributes field:**

```
[
    {
        "site": "site1",
        "categories": [
            "site1 cat1",
            "site1 cat2",
            "site1 cat3"
        ]
    },
    {
        "site": "site2",
        "categories": [
            "site2 cat1",
            "site2 cat2"
        ]
    }
]
```

My question is that have I put above JSON data in proper format for doing various further operations (CRUD)?

Or whether it should have a key `attributes` for easy accessing the data:

```
{
    "attributes": [
        {
            "site": "site1",
            "categories": [
                "site1 cat1",
                "site1 cat2",
                "site1 cat3"
            ]
        },
        {
            "site": "site2",
            "categories": [
                "site2 cat1",
                "site2 cat2"
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: Not really.. How are you planning to query your db

Comment: @IndraKumarS using MySQL JSON functions.

Answer (score 1):

If you must use embedded JSON for this, then either format will work, but the first one will be sufficient. For example, you can use `$[0].site` to access the site of the first element in the list. [See [the documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/json.html) for a full listing of how to query JSON in MySQL.]

**However,** please consider whether you really need JSON for this at all. Just because a feature (like JSON) is *supported* in MySQL doesn't mean it's always a good idea to use. The problem with JSON in MySQL is that you're bypassing the very point of the 'S' in Structured Query Language: the constructs of SQL like fields, tables, keys, etc. enforce a well-defined relational structure. JSON, by contrast, while still structured, does not enforce a *specific* relational structure.

Instead of using JSON to hold a product's attributes, first consider formalizing those attributes, for example with more tables:

```
Table: product_categories
+----------+-------+-------------+
|product_id|site_id|category_name|
+----------+-------+-------------+
|     1    | site1 |     cat1    |
|     1    | site1 |     cat2    |
|    ...   |  ...  |      ...    |
+----------+-------+-------------+
```

Then you can use joins and other traditional relational functionality, which after all is the point of a relational database like MySQL.